# A question on injective linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

I was wondering about the following question:

Assume that $B$ is a real-valued matrix of dimension $m\times l$. Is it true that if for all non-zero $k\times m$-dimensional matrices $A$ that $AB\neq 0$, then $B$ must be injective (i.e., $\text{rank}(B)=l$)?

Further; does it make a difference if we assume that $k=l$ and $AB$ is invertible?

Comment: Take $m=l=k=2$ and $A=B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I corrected the statement. I need it to be true for ALL As simultaneously.

Comment: Do you maybe mean $BA \neq 0$?

Comment: No, I do not. I have a feeling that the result stated is wrong, but I fail to conjure up a counter-example.

Comment: Ah ok then take any $B$ that is injective but not surjective. This gives a counter example; see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase your criterion, for every $A_1, A_2$ a pair of $k \times m$ matrices with $A_1 \neq A_2$, we have $(A_1-A_2)B = A_1B-A_2B \neq 0$, so $A_1 B \neq A_2 B$. Phrased this way, it is precisely the criterion in category theory for $B$ to be an *epimorphism*, which is equivalent in the category of vector spaces to being *surjective* (i.e., $\operatorname{rank}(B)=m$).

In more basic language, consider $k=1$. Then $A$ is simply a row vector, and you're stating the criterion for $B$ to be injective on row vectors, i.e., the rows of $B$ are linearly independent. It is a standard result that this is equivalent to the columns being spanning, i.e., $B$ is surjective on column vectors.

If $k=l$ and $AB$ is invertible, then $B$ is necessarily injective and $A$ is necessarily surjective. This is easy to see by $$Bv=0 \implies ABv = 0 \implies (AB)^{-1}AB v = 0 \iff v=0,$$
and dually for $A$ being surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is equivalent to $B$ being surjective. Assume that $B$ is surjective. Then $AB=0$ implies that $A=0$, simply by composition of linear maps. If $B$ is not surjective, say with some $v\notin Im\,B$. Then take any $A$ such that $A(v)\neq 0$ but $A\vert_{Im\, B} = 0$. This will then satisfy $AB=0$ although $A$ is non-zero.

If you write $BA\neq 0$ in your statement you would detect injectivity by a similar argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption suggests that the rows of $B$ are linearly independent. There is a lemma which says [a matrix is surjective iff the rows are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005793/simple-proof-of-the-following-a-matrix-a-is-onto-if-and-only-if-its-rows-are). I think you cannot say for sure $B$ is injective, unless you assume $BA \neq 0$, which is the result of [a related similar lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482512/t-is-injective-if-and-only-if-the-columns-of-the-matrix-representing-the-t-a).